# Show selected value in dropdown after submit button

Tags: php

I am trying to print selected value in drop-down after submit button. 
here is my php function.

```
if( !function_exists('mad_get_towns_list') ):

    function mad_get_towns_list(){

        $towns_list='';

        if(mad_get_towns()){

            foreach(mad_get_towns() as $town){
                $towns_list .= '<option value="'.$town.'">'.$town.'</option>';
            }

            return $towns_list;
        }

        return false;

    }

endif;
```

And Here I am getting all list .Problem is that when I am submit the button then its showing Any ,Its does not showing selected value .

```
<select name="city_location" class="custom-select full-width" id="s_country" data-live-search="true" value="<?php echo $_POST['city_location'];?>">
                                              <option value="">Any</option>
                                            <?php
                                                print_r(mad_get_towns_list());
                                                ?>
                                        </select>
```

Comment: Little advice: instead of calling `mad_get_towns()` twice, you should store the result into a variable and use it into your `if` and `foreach()`.

Comment: Syscall@ok can you Help me regarding this .I am very confuse why this is not working

Comment: what's the mad_get_towns() function doing? Can we see the code for this?

Comment: Juakali92@please read the code after if condition mad_get_towns_list() function is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `selected` attribute instead of value for the `<select>` tag.
So, you could pass the current value into your function to add this attribute :

```
if (!function_exists('mad_get_towns_list')) :
function mad_get_towns_list($selected_value) { // pass value, see below

    $towns_list='';

    $towns = mad_get_towns(); // store variable
    if (!empty($towns)) {
        foreach($towns as $town) {
            $selected = $selected_value == $town ? " selected" : "" ; // create select attribute
            $towns_list .= '<option value="'.$town.'" '.$selected.'>'.$town.'</option>';
        }
    }
    return $towns_list;
}
endif;
?>
<select name="city_location" class="custom-select full-width" id="s_country" data-live-search="true">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <?php
        $selected = isset($_POST['city_location']) ? $_POST['city_location'] : '' ;
        echo mad_get_towns_list($selected) ;
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Syscall@perfect thanks for help@you are awesome , can you describe the addition line for attribute , what selected attribute is working

Comment: @webduniya Sorry, I haven't seen your comment. It tests if the value passed in parameter of the function is the same of current town. If yes, it appends `selected` into the variable. To see in action, submit your form, and then, look at the source of your webpage, you'll see an option with an attribute `selected`.